# opening a new tab in node.js selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a new tab using selenium-webdriver. But it opens the browser and stays there. It fails to open a new tab. What am I missing?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;
  Keys = webdriver.Key;
  var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
   .forBrowser('firefox')
   .build();
  driver.get('https://google.com');
  driver.wait(until.titleIs('Google'), 5000);
  var selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");  
  driver.findElement(By.css("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
  driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK `webdriver.Key.chord` doesn't send key combinations events, so it couldn't be used in this way.

To open new tab try to use `JavaScript`.

Try below and let me know if it doesn't work as expected:

```
driver.executeScript('window.open("newURL");');
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I have seen my pattern in JAVA. Wondering why not possible with node.js

Answer (score 5):

**Note: This feature works with Selenium 4 and later versions.**

```
// Opens a new tab and switches to new tab
await driver.switchTo().newWindow('tab');

// Opens a new window and switches to new window
await driver.switchTo().newWindow('window');
```

Source: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/